# Child div will not over-lap parent div with a z-index added

Tags: html, css, position, css-position

I am having issues getting my `viewproductbutton` to go overtop of it's parent div. I have added a `z-index` to the element and have tried to position it with `position: relative;` and `position: absolute;`. Nothing is getting it to position in the top right corner as I want it.

Here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Lrdswa5a/

What am I not doing right

Comment: The viewproductbutton div. That is what makes up the button that says "View Product Details". It needs to be in the top right corner of the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lrdswa5a/5/

If you replace your '.featuredproductspic' and '.viewproductbutton' with the following:

```
.featuredproductspic {
  /*width: 100%;*/
  border: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
  min-height: 350px;
  max-height: 350px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
```

and

```
.viewproductbutton {
  width: 150px;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  background-color: #909090;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
}
```

Then the button is on the top right of the image.

Cheers!

Comment: Didn't help for me. I am looking to get the hover part of this to display in the top right. I think something with my code is stopping it in the hover part.

Comment: So, you want the `.viewproductbutton` to appear in the top right of the screen? Cause then you can just remove the `position:relative`  from `featuredproductspic`

Comment: Nevermind, you are answer worked. I just had to put it in the hover part and do one other change. Thanks!